# getting first loop on php and record as 1

Tags: php, loops, foreach

How can i track the first foreach loop and mark it as 1? I used the modulus but sometimes results two results as $i == 1. I want a single result with 1 for every single loop of the first loop.

Here is my code.

```
$array  = array(
                array('val'  =>   1), //Mark this as $i = 1;
                array('val'  =>   1), //Mark this as $i = 0;
                array('val'  =>   2), //Mark this as $i = 1;
                array('val'  =>   2), //Mark this as $i = 0;
                array('val'  =>   3)  //Mark this as $i = 1;
                );

foreach($array as $key1=>$arr1) {

        foreach($array as $key2=>$arr2) {

               $i = ($key1 % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;

               //Output expected
               // 1 vs 1
               // 2 vs 2
               // 3

               break;

        }

}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: `foreach($array as $key2=>$arr2) {` => `foreach($arr1 as $key2=>$arr2) {`

Comment: what's the output you expected ?

Answer (score 0):

you cant put same name to both arrays `$array` , change

```
foreach($array as $key1=>$arr1) {

        foreach($array as $key2=>$arr2) {
```

to

```
   foreach($array as $key1=>$arr1) {

            foreach($array123 as $key2=>$arr2) {
```

Comment: i just want it to display on a single loop